# How to get push notification on/off status programmatically to send it to my webserver?

Tags: android, web, notifications, push

I have implemented push notification in my app sucessfully using GCM.
I Am using my dotnet webserver to send push message to my app vai GCM Server.
I have stored GCM Registered Id in database on my server.
Now I want to check that if user has manually disable/off the notification for my app (by going through setting), so that i can send request to my webserver that not to send push message to that device by removing GCM ID from database(unregistering).

I know push messages are delivered to my app and are ignored if notification is off but my problem is that my app is going to be used by more 100000 users/devices and if only few of them are using notification on, then there is unnecessary traffic of sending push messages over 100000 devices/users.

So is there any way to know the status of the notification on/off programmatically so that i can send request to deregister the app on my web server?

I have googled and found that there is no way to find it out, so is any one has other solution for my scenario.

Please help me on this as i am stuck on this from last couple of days.

Thanks in advance,

Ketan Bhangale

Answer (score 0):

Store user status in **SharedPreference** and check status while displaying notification.

same status you can store on your server and sort list of sender with status.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to disable an app’s notifications is only for devices currently running Android 4.1+ Jelly Bean. Also there seems to be no documented way to know the value for notification flag(check box) in default application settings.

**Simply you need to maintain that manually**. Say first create a web service for update "notification setting" . The app will send the value for notification say "true" or "false" as chooses by user fro our app settings menu.

`Now at server side store that value for notification_flag corresponding to that user in your db`.

Before sending the notification to the user on your desired even(as per app requirement when to send notification) , check first the value of the flag before firing the send notification msg on the device id for that user.

Also finally to be more reliable at app end too , `check the value for that flag before showing the notification in the app when the message arrived`.

Comment: many thanks for the quick reply.....As per your solution i need to keep one notification setting in my app and based on that functionality will work....... But is there any way to know the status of notification which user manually do outside the app i.e. check/uncheck of the notification box in the devices setting?

Comment: @Ketan The ability to disable an app’s notifications is only for devices currently running Android 4.1+ Jelly Bean. Also there seems to be no documented way to know the value for that.